# Ruby on rails en Windows 10

Tags: rubygems

¿Cómo instalar Ruby on Rails en Windows 10 correctamente? Para evitar problemas con gemas o archivos de configuración.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar railsinstaller el enlace es el siguiente:  http://railsinstaller.org/en tambien podrias hecharle un ojo a cloud9 en el siguiente enlace https://c9.io/login es un IDE para que puedas desarrollar tus proyectos desde el navegador sin necesidad de instalar nada